# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 4822 (1.io)

Tags: image, flutter, dart, crash, fatal-error

I have an issue with my project, it's contain about 200 assets image, it's about 130 mega byte, without using internet, it's showing the image slowly after few minuts it's crash, I tried to clean and make new project but I get the same error.
here is my log

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
Restarted application in 29,624ms.

F/libc    ( 4781): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 4822 (1.io)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_google_phone_x86/generic_x86:7.0/NYC/4409132:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
pid: 4781, tid: 4822, name: 1.io  >>> com.company.project <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
    eax 00000000  ebx 8c29dac4  ecx a7880000  edx 9868b500
    esi 05b8d800  edi 00000000
    xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 0000003b  xss 0000007b
    eip 8ba42285  ebp 8a201018  esp 8a200ff0  flags 00010286
backtrace:
    #00 pc 000af285  /data/app/com.company.project-1/lib/x86/libflutter.so (offset 0x1208000)
Lost connection to device.
```

here is my code

```
  myMethod(context) {
    return GridView.count(
      childAspectRatio: 1.0,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      crossAxisSpacing: 18,
      mainAxisSpacing: 18,
      children: getTypesMethods.map<Widget>((data) {
    
        return myTabButton(
          foodType: data,
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }

myTabButton(FoodType foodtype){
   return Container(
        width: 0.4 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 0.4 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
          border: Border.all(color: Color(0xffEBEBEB), width: 1),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 0.4 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: 0.27 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    image: new DecorationImage(
                      colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(
                          Colors.white.withOpacity(1), BlendMode.dstATop),
                      image: new AssetImage(foodType.image),
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                // child: Image.asset(
                //   foodType.image,
                //   fit: BoxFit.fill,
                // ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
                width: 0.4 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: 0.1 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    foodType.typeName,
                    style: TextStyle(fontFamily: fontBold, color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                )),
          ],
        ),
      );
}
```

please help me with my issue, I have this problem for week and I need to finisth this project

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I have the same error

Comment: @victcdva, yes I solved it but I don't remember how or in any project, i'll try to find the project and answer you

Comment: Yeah, I got you, thank you

Comment: @Husamuldeen hello, do you remember?

Answer (score 0):

for me, I upgraded my emulator from android 6.0 to android 13, which is the latest version. Then the error disappeared.